# ¿Cómo puedo usar una imagen como cursor?

Tags: html

No he podido poner un cursor, estoy usando el siguiente código, hice una imagen PNG y la convertí a formato cur.

```
<Style type="text/css">
body{
cursor:url("cursor.cur"), crosshair;}
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Esto](https://jsfiddle.net/fvobawt5/) se puede hacer:

```css
div {
    background-color:green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
div#es_so {
    background-color:red;
    cursor: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/favicon.ico), pointer;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="es_so"></div>
<div></div>
```

Tienes que usar `pointer` y cualquier imagen.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Comment: No te preocupes lo escribiste bastante bien

Comment: @BetaM Siéntase libre de corregir dónde puede ser útil!

Comment: No para nada, la comunicación es bastante fluida por que lo escribiste muy bien, Bienvenido a SO en español. :D